# Get website's IP address using Flex 4 AIR app?

Tags: apache-flex, air, ip, ping, flashbuilder4

How do I get the IP address of a certain website using Flex 4 via an AIR application? I know that this is do-able using **ping website.com** but how can I replicate the same only this time, using AS3 in Flex 4 and as an AIR application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DNSResolver`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/dns/DNSResolver.html) class to look up IP addresses of a domain name. The link is to ActionScript documentation that has an example you can use.